# AttributeError: xmlNode instance has no attribute 'isCountNode'

Tags: python, xml, centos, libxml2, centos5

I'm using libxml2 in a Python app I'm writing, and am trying to run some test code to parse an XML file. The program downloads an XML file from the internet and parses it. However, I have run into a problem.

With the following code:

```
xmldoc = libxml2.parseDoc(gfile_content)

droot = xmldoc.children         # Get document root
dchild = droot.children         # Get child nodes

while dchild is not None:
        if dchild.type == "element":
                print "\tAn element with ", dchild.isCountNode(), "child(ren)"
                print "\tAnd content", repr(dchild.content)
        dchild = dchild.next
xmldoc.freeDoc();
```

...which is based on the code example found on [this article on XML.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/05/14/py-xml.html), I receive the following error when I attempt to run this code on Python 2.4.3 (CentOS 5.2 package).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xml.py", line 25, in ?
    print "\tAn element with ", dchild.isCountNode(), "child(ren)"
AttributeError: xmlNode instance has no attribute 'isCountNode'
```

I'm rather stuck here.

**Edit:** I should note here I also tried IsCountNode() and it still threw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isCountNode should read "lsCountNode" (a lower-case "L")

Comment: Is it the same error? (i.e. xmlNode instance has no attribute "lsCountNode"?)